# JavaCV библиотеки

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток!
Возникла необходимость разработки с помощью javaCV. Нашла достаточно исходников с примерами, но не удается подключить import name.audet.samuel.javacv....

Скачала уже кучу библиотек и все не то. Может кто-то подскажет, что именно нужно скачать.

Comment: Напишите, что за ошибка появляется при попытке запустить программу с вот этим import name.audet.samuel.javacv....

Comment: @Rumato, does not exist

Comment: вы правильно всё установили? посмотрите наврное тут http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~cs10/install/javacv-win/

и потом запустите что-нибудь из отпримеров от сюда http://code.google.com/p/javacv/

Я в java не силён, но если у вас, прям все примеры не запускаются, то думаю дело в установке или путях до библиотеки.

Comment: @Rumato, сейчас попробую еще раз. Просто уже кучу всего наустанавливала...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Общий механизм подключение внешних либ такой:

1. Берем внешнюю либу (обычно jar, иногда zip, редко набор файлов .class)
2. Убеждаемся что это то что надо. То есть если наш исходник требует нечто вроде `name.audet.samuel.javacv`, то в прилагаемом jar/zip должен быть каталог `name/audet/samuel/javacv` - по другому никак. Как узнать листинг jar/zip надеюсь рассказывать не надо.
3. Помещаем либу в отдельный подкаталог своего проекта
4. Включаем каталог/файл(ы) в `CLASSPATH`.

Ключевой вопрос что такое `CLASSPATH` и как с этим жить.

1. В самом дебильном варианте CLASSPATH задается как переменная среды OS примерно как: `set CLASSPATH=<мой каталог/файл>`
2. В более продвинутом варианте можно задавать в качестве параметра к компилятору `javac -cp <мой каталог/файл>`
3. В еще более продвинутом варианте при работе через IDE - всегда имеется понятие внешней библиотеки и его подключения. Например, в Eclipse [это так](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java))
4. Есть вариант включения библиотеки при работе через автоматические сборщики ant/maven/gradle - это уже отдельная тема

**Update**

Касательно пакета: `name.audet.samuel.javacv.jna` читаем issue-tracker и видим:

> "name.audet.samuel.javacv.jna" was the package name I used for old versions of 
> JavaCV. I have since been renamed it to "com.googlecode.javacv.cpp", so please 
> update your source files accordingly.

Переименуйте в примерах ссылки на пакет и все.

Comment: Как добавить библиотеки я знаю. Я скачала библиотеки com.googlecode.java.*
Но во всех примерах в интернете используются name.audet.samuel.javacv.*
Вот я и парюсь который день, где взять их,т.к. в com.goodlecode.javacv.* аналога нет

Comment: @Мария_1 я обновил ответ

Comment: @Barmaley, к сожалению это уже пробовалось и такого импорта не находит. ...does not exist...

Comment: @Мария_1 Листинг jar какой? Какие там каталоги/пакеты/классы лежат внутри?

Comment: @Barmaley структура папок совершенно не аналогична name.audet.samuel поэтому я просто все классы искала в гугле, как можно подключить) этим решила свою проблему)

Comment: @Мария_1 (facepalm)